# Magento 2 How to control Customer Login

Tags: magento2, login, plugin, customer-login

Here am trying to add some condition before customer login. but I'm not able put plugin for Login.
Here is my code

```
app/code/Praveenn/Pvnn/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="MyCucomtLoginAccountLoginPost" type="Praveenn\Pvnn\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin code

```
<?php

namespace Praveenn\Pvnn\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,$result)
    {   
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PRAVLogin.log'); 
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); 
        $logger->info('here'); 
    }
}
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get Help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your di.xml code seems right. But issue have at your  `Praveenn\Pvnn\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost.php`

As your are using [around plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods) .your second parameter `$result` type is   `callable or \Closure`. and After That if you want call original execute method then use `$returnValue = $result();`  and return `$returnValue`

```
<?php

namespace Praveenn\Pvnn\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,callable $result)
    {   
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PRAVLogin.log'); 
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); 
        $logger->info('here'); 
        $returnValue = $result();
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Amit Bera for helping, I updated  `LoginPost.php` and checked with `callable or \Closure` but its not still logging.

Comment: i think for permission issue `PRAVLogin.log` is not creating.So  create PRAVLogin.log at var/log folder and give rewrite  permission to this file

Comment: I run `sudo chmod -R 777 generated/code/ pub/static/ pub/media/ var/` before and after running `upgrade,deploy & c:f` but still same, not logging